# libgdx android как добавить dialog box

Tags: java, android

Необходимо добавить диалоговое окно как на этой картинке. Как реализовывать текст в диалоговом окне с помощью библиотек libgdx? Как сделать так чтобы по нажатию на диалоговое окно менялся текст и желательно спрайт который находится рядом с этим диалоговым окном.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]